# Android PendingIntent FLAG_NO_CREATE does not return null

Tags: android, android-service, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-background

I have some trouble with PendingIntents. Every time my app is opened it will schedule some broadcasts.
My Problem is that already existing PendingIntents aren't recognized.

I know that the PendingIntents and the unterlaying Intents must be created with the same parameters.

Her is my code ... started in my Launcher Activity as a Asynctask.

```
        long nextExecute = getNextExecute(t);

        if (nextExecute > System.currentTimeMillis()) {

            int tt = 12;

            intent = new Intent(context, BirthExecutor.class);
            intent.putExtra(Target.ROW_ID, tt);

            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 10, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);

            if (pending != null) {

                manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextExecute, pending);

                BirthLog log = new BirthLog("Scheduled " + t.getFirstname() + " " + t.getLastname() + " on " + df.format(nextExecute));
                log_helper.insertLog(log);

            } else {

                BirthLog log = new BirthLog(t.getFirstname() + " " + t.getLastname() + " already active!");
                log_helper.insertLog(log);

            }

            intent = new Intent(LogAdapter.LOG_RECEIVE_ACTION);
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);

        }
```

The exact same code is executed each time but why is the pending variable not null? It has to be !!!
I have hardcoded the requestId also the putExtra is hardcoded.

**EDIT**

I have another function to update this schedules.
Only if I execute that function the PendingIntents aren't recognized any more. I tried to use the same context object as a static reference but also that failed.

```
public void updateTask(Target t) {

    if (t.getTime() == null || t.getRow() == null)
        return;

    Intent intent;
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.US);

    long nextExecute = getNextExecute(t);

    if (nextExecute > System.currentTimeMillis()) {

        intent = new Intent(static_context, BirthExecutor.class);
        intent.putExtra(Target.ROW_ID, 12);

        PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(static_context, 10, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        if (pending != null) {

            manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextExecute, pending);

            BirthLog log = new BirthLog("Scheduled " + t.getFirstname() + " " + t.getLastname() + " on " + df.format(nextExecute));
            log_helper.insertLog(log);
            Log.d("birth", log.getComment());

        } else {

            BirthLog log = new BirthLog(t.getFirstname() + " " + t.getLastname() + " ERROR. TIME: " + df.format(nextExecute));
            log_helper.insertLog(log);
            Log.d("birth", log.getComment());

        }

        intent = new Intent(LogAdapter.LOG_RECEIVE_ACTION);
        static_context.sendBroadcast(intent);

    }

}
```

**EDIT 2**

Ok it makes sence if it returns a non-null result if that pending-intent is already scheduled.
I have changed my code. Every time I rotate my phone the main activity onCreate is fired and the scheduling asynctask is executed. BUT the result is always null ?!?! It should be a non-null result if there is a scheduled pendingintent already, right?

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

    Intent intent;
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.US);

    for (Target t : target_helper.getAllTarget()) {

        long nextExecute = getNextExecute(t);

        if (nextExecute > System.currentTimeMillis()) {

            PendingIntent pending = getPendingIntent(context, t, false);

            if (pending != null) {

                BirthLog log = new BirthLog(t.getFirstname() + " " + t.getLastname() + " already active!");
                log_helper.insertLog(log);

            } else {

                manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextExecute, pending);

                BirthLog log = new BirthLog("Scheduled " + t.getFirstname() + " " + t.getLastname() + " on " + df.format(nextExecute));
                log_helper.insertLog(log);

            }

            intent = new Intent(LogAdapter.LOG_RECEIVE_ACTION);
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);

        }

    }

    return null;

}

private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(Context context, Target t, boolean update) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, BirthExecutor.class);
    intent.putExtra(Target.ROW_ID, t.getRow());

    if (update) {
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, t.getRow().intValue(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    } else {
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, t.getRow().intValue(), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

The documentation is incorrect. If you use `PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE` when calling `PendingIntent.getBroadcast()` it will return `null` **if no matching `PendingIntent` is found. Otherwise it will return the matching `PendingIntent`**.

The documentation says it is the other way around, but that's wrong :-(

Comment: omg if it is really like that grrr ... I will have a look ... thank you ;)

Comment: Actually, if you think about it for more than a few seconds, it is clear that it makes no sense to return `null` if there is a matching `PendingIntent` and non-null if there isn't one, since by setting `FLAG_NO_CREATE` you've indicated that you **don't want Android to create a new `PendingIntent`**. What should it return as a non-null result?

Comment: did you solve it ?
i am facing the exact same problem

Answer (score 4):

The system does exactly what the documentation says:

> int FLAG_NO_CREATE
>
> Flag indicating that if the described PendingIntent
> does not already exist, then simply return null instead of creating
> it.

With that said, if I don't want to start my task if it's already running, I do this:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
if (pendingIntent == null) {
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    // start it only it wasn't running already
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 10 * 60 * 1000, pendingIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and now I understand why and how to avoid it.

If I run the following lines for the **very first** time, my pendingIntent is null.

```
final Intent intentToCancel = new Intent(mContext, receiver);
intentToCancel.setAction(action);
final PendingIntent pendingIntentToCancel =
PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, requestCode, intentToCancel, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE | PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
```

However, if I schedule an alarm for this pendingIntent and then I cancel it, if I create again the pending intent with the lines above, it will not be null. Even if the alarm is cancelled.

The solution is : When I cancel the alarm, I also have to cancel the pending intent like that:

```
mAlarmManager.cancel(pendingIntentToCancel);
pendingIntentToCancel.cancel();
```

Comment: Great answer. Also, cancelling the pendingIntent was the trick. Thanks.